# JavaFX Application won't run when converted to executable

Tags: java, javafx

I've created a JavaFX GUI and it worked fine until I exported it as a JAR file and converted it to an Executable file.

Running it using VS Code `Run and Debug` works fine but, whenever I open the executable, which I exported from

[image: VSCode export jar button]

and converted using Launch4j, nothing happens.

But when I try to run it on the Terminal using
`Java -jar <filename>.jar`

It shows the error

`Error: Could not find or load main class ?jar`
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ?jar`

below is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch App",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "infixToPostfix.App",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path D:/Programming/Projects/School/javafx-sdk-19/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
        }
    ]
}
```

and bellow is my folder structure

[image: Folder Structure]

I've seen a few post that is related to the one I currently have but nothing helped. I'm new to JavaFX and i've been trying different solutions for hours. Maybe I just missed something important. Thank you in advance.

I've checked similar post but most of them are using IntelliJ or Eclipse. I've also seen some which uses VS Code and when I tried them, still nothing worked.

Comment: The error does not seem related to JavaFX, at least not directly. `ClassNotFoundException: ?jar` means that it tried to load a class named `?jar` as the main class, but that class could not be found (to be expected given that very odd name). My _guess_ is that somehow you have `Main-Class: ?jar` in the JAR's manifest file (though the `?` may simply be a character your console couldn't print). It should be something like `Main-Class: infixToPostfix.App`. I've never created a JAR file via VS Code, so I don't know what configuration you need to change.

Comment: Yes. Just as what I said, the problem came when I try to run the .exe which I got from exporting to jar and converting it to .exe using launch4j. Since, the .exe wouldn't run, I then tried to run the .jar file using command java -jar InfixtoPostfix.jar which well, resulted in the error I'm currently trying to fix. Also I'll try checking the `?` I just started learning JavaFX 4 days ago so maybe I just missed something. Thank you.

Comment: I have some experience with Java and JavaFX. I just finished programming a basic application for my study of software engineering. However, we were advised to use Jetbrains IntelliJ IDEA and Maven. With Maven it's really easy to get an executable .jar file. I wouldn't recommend using VSCode for any Java developer. VSCode is not really a full-fletch IDE and IntelliJ IDEA with extensive debugging tools built into it tailer specifically for Java.

Comment: However, if you provide some code maybe I could copy-paste it into my IDE and check it out if maybe I can get it running. I'm willing to put some time in.

Comment: I understand your issue. With Maeven we need to assign the Main class in the config file, like this: <mainClass>${project.mainClass}</mainClass> I don't know where you need to do it. Maybe in settings.json or launch.json. You need to check the Java VSCode plugin which provides you with the export function. Check the documentation and it will tell you where you need to put the Main class in the configuration file. I will also post this as an answer so you can thank me with points 

Answer (score 0):

## Config file

The error you got is a very similar one I got months ago when I first started to develop a JavaFX application. I needed to tell Maven what class my Main class was so that Maven could compile a .jar file for me

I understand your issue. With Maven we need to assign the Main class in the config file, like this: ${project.mainClass} I don't know where you need to do it. Maybe in settings.json or launch.json. You need to check the Java VSCode plugin which provides you with the export function. Check the documentation and it will tell you where you need to put the Main class in the configuration file.

### Example pom.xml file (Maven config file)

This is a Maven example and you need to do something similar. It's important that you also compile and tell the Java plugin to compile a single fat JAR with dependencies, otherwise, it won't run.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>My example project</name>
    <groupId>nl.hva</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_example_artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.mainClass>my_example_package_name.Main</project.mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath/>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries/>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries/>
                            <addExtensions/>
                            <classpathLayoutType/>
                            <classpathPrefix/>
                            <customClasspathLayout/>
                            <mainClass>${project.mainClass}</mainClass>
                            <packageName/>
                            <useUniqueVersions/>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <mode>development</mode>
                            <url>${project.url}</url>
                            <key>value</key>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### VS Code docs

VS Code docs also mention using Maven! So it's easy for me to help you because I have workable JavaFX 19 applications (in another IDE, but Maven is the same everywhere). See vscode docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project